# 'char' array issue, custom print function and strcpy_s problem

Tags: c++, arrays, strcpy

I just started C++ and now I'm making a simple program. But don't know how to fix this problem.
I'm not a native english speaker so some sentences may not be understandable.

```
int main()
{
    char test[5][4] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << test[i] << "\t";
    
    return 0;
}
```

with this simple code, I made a print function

```
void printTest(char* pArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << pArr[i] << "\t";
}
```

Then in my `main` function, I typed `printTest(*test);`
but the result was  'a       b       c               d'
while my expectation was 'abc def ghi jkl mno'

---

So I fixed `printTest` function like below
(changed const char* test[5][4] = { ... }
in main function)

```
void printTest(const char** pArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << pArr[i] << "\t";
}
```

which worked well.

The problem is, I want to use `strcpy_s` fucntion also.
`strcpy_s(test[0], "xyx");` like this.

As `strcpy_s` get char* for the first parameter (not const char*),
I think I need to use `char*` for my array, and print function.
While that thing cause a wrong printing issue.

Did i wrote something wrong in my `printTest` function?
Or Is there any way that I can use `strcpy_s` function with `const char*` parameter?

PS. I used `std::string` and made it as I expected.
But I want to have a understanding and control of Char array.

Comment: Why not just use `char**` as the parameter for `printTest`?

Comment: `strcpy_s` may not work the way you expect. For example, it doesn't prevent overflow by truncating the input and stopping before overrun, no it calls a handler function that defaults to aborting the program.

Comment: Second, [`strcpy_s` takes 3 parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy`), destination, maximum copy length, and source. [Microsoft has an groovy extra overload when called with an array that infers the length for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-170), but this is useless with pointers as array length cannot be inferred from a pointer.

Comment: Can you post the whole program you've got now which doesn't work?  It's not easy to understand what you're running because you've posted a `main()` which never calls `printTest()`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles  You must be kidding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `void printTest(const char** pArr)` will work with
`char test[5][4]`.

The c++ compiler should refuse something like

```cpp
    void printTest(const char** pArr);
    char test[5][4];
    printTest(test);
```

Because `test` is a `pointer to char [4]`,
while  printTest() expects a `pointer to char *`.

You may have interesting in this function:

```cpp
    void printTest2(const char (*pArr)[4] )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            std::cout << pArr[i] << "\t";
        std::cout <<  "\n";
    }
```

And the `const` keyword tells compiler (and what more important, the reader of your code) that "you won't modify the contents of 'pArr'". So compiler will not allow you to strcpy to pArr[i]. And this will compile and run.

```cpp
void printTest3(char (*pArr)[4] )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        strcpy(pArr[i], "123");
        std::cout << pArr[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout <<  "\n";
}
...
printTest3(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a but confused about he use of const.  Don't worry, it's happened to pretty much every one.

What's important to understand is that a non-const variable can be implicitly cast to a const variable at any time, but the reverse is not possible.

For your function PrintTest()

```
// Here, the const char** declaration is correct, your function only prints pArr, 
// and the caller should not expect the function to modify his precious data.

// Another thing to remember: pArr is valid (and thus constant) only within
// the scope of PrintTest().  It simply does not exist anywhere else. 

void printTest(const char** pArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << pArr[i] << "\t";
}

// this naturally allows printing of const and non-const data, as one would expects.

const char const_strings[2][4] = { "abc", "def" };

printTest(const_strings); // works!

// Note that if printTest() required a non_const pointer, the line above
// would not compile.  
// const_strings being const, there is no way to modify it using strcpy_s();

//  The code below also works fine, 

char modifiable_strings[2][4] = { "tuv", "xyz" };

printTest(modifiable_strings); // works!

strcpy_s(modifiable_strings[0], "abc");  // is OK, because modifiable is not const.

printTest(modifiable_strings); // works, with different output!
```